# Handlebars page not showing data from Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Handlebars not showing data from Mysql

I'm using express, sequelize and data from Mysql to show a list of flights in a handlebars page.
In my console the data is being displayed but in the handlebars page, nothing appears.

I just started learning handlebars and express usage in node so I'm a little bit clueless on how to solve this.

Here is what I've tried in app.js:

```
//importações de módulos
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const handlebars = require("express-handlebars");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

//conectando com o banco
const sequelize = new Sequelize("db", "user", "password", {
    host: "host",
    dialect: "mysql"
})

sequelize.authenticate().then(function(){
    console.log("deu certo!");
}).catch(function(){
    console.log("aAaAaAaAaAaAai")
})

const Voo = sequelize.define("Voo", {
    ID_VOO: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(100), 
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    ORIGEM: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    DESTINO: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    DT_PARTIDA: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    DT_CHEGADA: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    HR_SAIDA: {
        type: Sequelize.TIME,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    HR_CHEGADA: {
        type: Sequelize.TIME,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    VO_AERONAVE: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    }

}, {tableName: "voo", 
    timestamps: false,
})

//sincronizando model com banco de dados
Voo.sync().then(() => {
    console.log('Tabela sincronizada com sucesso');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Erro ao sincronizar tabela:', error);
  });

//buscando registros no banco
Voo.findAll().then((voos) => {
    app.post("/passagensAereas", function(req, res){
        res.render("passagensAereas", {voos: voos});
        //res.send("testando" + req.body.Origem + "\n" + req.body.Destino + "\n" + req.body.dataSaida);
    })
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Erro ao consultar tabela:', error);
  });
  
//=========================================================================================


//config
    //template engine
    app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

//rotas
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
})


app.listen(8083, function(){
    console.log("aAaAaAaAai está funcionando mesmo")
})
```

And here is my handlebars page:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="img/Logo-SKYIFSP.png">
    </header>
    <section>
        <div id="passagensAereas">
            <h2>Passagens aéreas</h2>
            <div id="box">
                <h1>Lista de voos</h1>
                <ul> 
                    {{#each voos}}
                    <li>{{this.origem}}</li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <h5 id="copyright">© 2022 - 2023 Symcode soluções de software - Todos os direitos reservados.</h5>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not really using the db credentials in const sequelize this line is just an example

Comment: I would begin by logging my data from within the template so that I can see what data it is getting. For example, by adding `{{log this}}` before the `{{#each voos}}` line.

Comment: Why so you declare your post handler inside `findAll` callback?